# Manipulating matrices and data frames into 3-column data frames with same R script

Tags: r, class, matrix, dataframe

I need a short R script that can reorganise both large matrices and data.frames into 3 column data.frames. My current script can handle matrices but returns an error message when I input a data.frame. Any advice on how I can force it to handle both classes?

```
library(FD)

ds<-dummy$abun #a matrix

#reorganize into 3 column data.frame 
q<-rep.int(row.names(ds),ncol(ds))
p<-rep(colnames(ds),each = (nrow(ds)))
ssf<-data.frame(q,p,as.numeric(ds)) 
names(ssf) <- c("site", "species", "freq")
```

Works fine but I want it to be able to reorganize both matrices and dataframes (i.e.)

```
ds<-as.data.frame(dummy$abun) #a matrix

#reorganize into 3 column data.frame 
q<-rep.int(row.names(ds),ncol(ds))
p<-rep(colnames(ds),each = (nrow(ds)))
ssf<-data.frame(q,p,as.numeric(ds)) 
names(ssf) <- c("site", "species", "freq")
```

returns

```
'Error in data.frame(q, p, as.numeric(ds)) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: Untested, but since the second one is a `data.frame`, `as.numeric` won't have the same effect as it does on a matrix. Try changing that line to `as.numeric(unlist(ds, use.names = FALSE))` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're just trying to do `setNames(cbind(rownames(ds), stack(as.data.frame(ds))), c("Site", "Freq", "Species"))`. See also `melt` from "reshape2".

Comment: Thanks, changing the as.numeric() line worked great. Using setNames also works and is shorter but switches the column order from site,species, freq to site, freq, species. @AnandaMahto If you would like to post this as an answer I can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. While `as.numeric` will create a simple vector from a `matrix`, it won't do the same for a `data.frame`. A `data.frame` is a `list` of vectors, while a `matrix` is a vector with a dimensional attribute. As such, an alternative would be to use `unlist` first:

   ```
   as.numeric(unlist(ds, use.names = FALSE))
   ```
2. It seems like you're actually just trying to create a "long" form of your data. In this case, explore `stack` from base R and `melt` from "reshape2". A possible approach would be:

   ```
   out <- cbind(rownames(ds), stack(as.data.frame(ds)))
   names(out) <- c("vector", "of", "names") ## Replace as required :)
   ```

   or

   ```
   library(reshape2)
   out <- melt(as.matrix(ds))
   ```